# Why late static binding doesn't work inside anonymous function?

Tags: php, hhvm

I have PHP code like below

```
<?php

class Test {

    public static function bar(array $ids) {
        return array_map(function($id) {
            return static::foo($id);
        }, $ids);
    }

    public static function foo($id) {
        return "halo {$id}";
    }
}

class Test1 extends Test {

    public static function foo($id) {
        return "hi {$id}";
    }
}

$className = Test1::class; 
//Let's say line above is input from user or some other code.
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
print_r(call_user_func([$className, 'bar'], $ids));
```

I expected the code above will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi 1
    [1] => hi 2
    [2] => hi 3
    [3] => hi 4
    [4] => hi 5
)
```

but weirdly, it returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => halo 1
    [1] => halo 2
    [2] => halo 3
    [3] => halo 4
    [4] => halo 5
)
```

Why is that?

My PHP version is below

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

But oddly again, HHVM returns what I expected.

```
HipHop VM 3.6.5 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.6.5-0-g20a30678cd67fad96602ffd93e69780d001ce57f
Repo schema: 53a4026d3732c3584cffef19fa47fea655be3c4f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pre-5.5.14. See [the changelog](https://secure.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.14) for more information. Likely this:

```
Fixed bug #66622 (Closures do not correctly capture the late bound class (static::) in some cases).
```

Edit: link to confirm bug in different versions: https://3v4l.org/BiYk2

Comment: PHP 7 is coming soon :D